# Use JQuery .animate to move an element up and down infinitly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Right now, I have the following JQuery `.animate` command which moves a line image from `top:0px` to `top:200px`.

```
$("#scanner").animate({ top: '200px' }, 2000);
```

How can I animate the line image from `200px` back to `0px` and so on, to `200px` , repetativly, infinitly?

(To clarify, the animation is like a barcode scanner).

Comment: Use css instead, why script?

Comment: @skobaljic This is a part of a whole script. The animation will use variables, so it has to be a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it as success callback

```
function topInc(){
  $("#scanner").animate({ top: '200px' }, 2000, topDec);
}

function topDec(){
  $("#scanner").animate({ top: '0' }, 2000, topInc);
}

topInc();
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone needs it, the CSS solution would be:

```css
.scan-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#scanner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: none rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    animation: scanning 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scanning {
    0% {
        top: 0;
    }
    50% {
        top: calc(100% - 10px);
    }
    100% {
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="scan-box">
    Scanning...
    <div id="scanner"></div>
</div>
```

As a bonus, some customization can be done via additional styles or using [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables):

```css
:root {
    --data-from: 0;
    --data-to: 100%;
}

.scan-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.scanner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: none rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    animation: scanning 3s linear infinite;
}

.scanner-ease-in-out {
    animation: scanning 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes scanning {
    0% {
        top: var(--data-from);
    }
    50% {
        top: calc(var(--data-to) - 10px);
    }
    100% {
        top: var(--data-from);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="scan-box">
    Scanning...
    <div class="scanner"></div>
</div>

<div class="scan-box">
    Scanning...
    <div class="scanner scanner-ease-in-out"></div>
</div>

<div class="scan-box">
    Scanning...
    <div class="scanner" style="--data-from:25%;--data-to:75%"></div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79nmq0p6/2/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's good you docmented the CSS approach.